# How to make this UI In Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[image]

How to make this UI in Flutter Framwork

Answer (score 1):

1. Rounded corner Card with text
2. Button with navigation to next card
3. Button surrounded by Progress bar with increase of 25% on each click on button, initial value is 25%
4. Cards are maybbe horizontaly scrollable